# How can I remove, with the event Onclick, the objects pushed into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, onclick

For learning purposes I am creating a Todo app in JavaScript.
I have a function that takes the input value(Task) and push it to an array of objects.

I want to be able to remove the object task out of the array listOfTask when button delete is clicked and I want to switch the completed property of task to true when button completed is clicked. My problem is that the user can click randomly any object in the array. So I can not link the event click to the object that I want to manipulate using index. Any ideas on how to achieve this will be highly appreciated. By the way, this is my fisrt time posting a question so please let me know if my question needs improvment or clarification.

```
let listofTask=[];
function addTask(){
 let taskAdded= document.getElementById('input1').value;

 let task=new Object;
 task.task=taskAdded;
 task.completed=false;

 listOfTask.push(task);
 appendTask(listOfTask);
   
}
```

So the function appendTask() craetes two buttons per each task and print them into the HTML

```
function appendTask(array){
    
    if(array.length>0){
        
        let div=document.getElementById('show-tasks');
        
        let ul= document.createElement('ul');
        
        let completedButton= document.createElement('input');
        completedButton.value= 'Completed';
        completedButton.type='button';
        completedButton.onclick=function completedTask(){
            this.parentNode.classList.add("mark-completed");
        }
        
        let deleteButton= document.createElement('input');
        deleteButton.value='Delete';
        deleteButton.type='button';
        
        deleteButton.onclick= function deleteTask(){
            this.parentNode.remove();
        }

        ul.innerHTML=ul.innerHTML+`<li>${array[array.length-1].task}</li>
                                     `;

        ul.appendChild(completedButton);
        ul.appendChild(deleteButton);
        div.appendChild(ul)
        

    
}
}
```

At this point I am able to succesfully mark a task as completed and remove it from the HTML but I want to be able to manipulate the objects inside the array as well.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always glad to see new developers diving right in!
One way of achieving your desired goal is to give each `Object` a property `id` which uniquely identifies it. Then, when clicking the `delete`-button, you can use the Array function [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the element to remove.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented your solution and ir worked well,

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked! :)